# Google Toolbar History when Using Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

When using Internet Explorer I have added the Google tool bar and its search window. As far as I know the Google tool bar does not exist on Edge. I have specified that Google is my default search provider for Edge and that seems to work.

However, on Internet Explorer when I click on the Google search space, I get a pull down which shows my search history. I find this useful. However, there does not seem to be a similar functionality when searching using Google from Edge, either from a link to "WWW.GOOGLE.COM" nor from Edge search box.

Can I still see my Google search history and reuse the search text in Edge?

Comment: In Windows 10, in Chromium Edge, and in Google Chrome, search history is in the  More ... menu under History. Same for both browsers.  Google.com has search history in that window.

Comment: OK, I see them now, but the IE Google Toolbar window with its pull down was a whole lot more convenient...  Oh well, I guess this is progress...